# WPF List files from a folder

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, binding

I want to get a number of songs from a folder and list their names in a WPF Listview. 
I also want each item in the list view to be a draggable file and can be copied from the list to the desktop. I've achieved this on one button, using the code:

```
Point mpos = e.GetPosition(null);
Vector diff = this.start - mpos;
string[] files = new String[1];
files[0] = @"C:\Song1.mp3";
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, files),
   DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

For that each item in the list needs to have a filepath string associated with it.
How do I:
1. Get the files from a folder and list them.
2. Associate with each one a filepath string for the dragging.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Directory.GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) to get all the file paths in a folder and then use [Path.GetFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) (or [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx)) on each path returned to get just the file names.

Comment: Another question- How can I drag multiple items in the listview?

Comment: Im not entiery sure about dragging and dropping but setting the [ListBox.SelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selectionmode.aspx) property to `Multiple` might be enough